# Add a react component into elementor and allow it to dynamically get data

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to replace an elementor widget by one I custom made myself using react, in the code I have below I'm passing the array as an example since i thought getting it dynamically would be similar, I'm using tailwind for the react component.

The fields that I'm trying to get from the post types are the same as the ones represented by the mockItems

I'm trying to find any step by step but it all seems to be missing some crucial steps that I don't know.

Sorry if the answer is obvious or more straightforward than I think it is.

This is the code for my react component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSpringCarousel } from 'react-spring-carousel';

const Carousel2 = () => {
  const mockItems = [
    {
      id: 'item-1',
      title: 'slide 1',
      image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/80x80',
      loremIpsum: 'Short Lorem Ipsum.',
      number: 123,
      twoWordLorem: 'Two Word',
    },
    {
      id: 'item-2',
      title: 'slide 2',
      image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/80x80',
      loremIpsum: 'Long Lorem Ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
      number: 456,
      twoWordLorem: 'Another Slide',
    },
    {
      id: 'item-3',
      title: 'slide 3',
      image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/80x80',
      loremIpsum: 'Long Lorem Ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Long Lorem Ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.," // Example of a very long Lorem Ipsum',
      number: 789,
      twoWordLorem: 'Dynamic Content',
    },
  ];
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(mockItems[0].id);

  const {
    carouselFragment,
    slideToPrevItem,
    slideToNextItem,
    useListenToCustomEvent,
  } = useSpringCarousel({
    itemsPerSlide: 3,
    withLoop: true,
    initialStartingPosition: 'center',
    gutter: 24,
    items: mockItems.map((item) => {
      return {
        ...item,
        renderItem: (
          <div
            key={item.id}
            className={`grid aspect-[2] w-full place-items-center text-lg pt-[60px] select-none text-black bg-white border-2 border-teal-400 shadow-2xl rounded-md transition-all duration-700 ${
              currentSlide === item.id ? 'z-10 scale-150' : ''
            }`}
          >
            <img src={item.image} alt={`Slide ${item.title}`} className="mb-4 shadow-2xl absolute top-[-40px] rounded-full border-teal-400 border-8" />
            <p className="text-center">{item.loremIpsum}</p>
            <p className="font-bold text-teal-600 mb-2">{item.number}</p>
            <p className="text-sm">{item.twoWordLorem}</p>
          </div>
        ),
      };
    }),
  });

  useListenToCustomEvent((event) => {
    if (event.eventName === 'onSlideStartChange') {
      setCurrentSlide(event?.nextItem?.id);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="py-20 relative">
        <button onClick={slideToPrevItem} className="absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-full left-[10%]">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6 mr-10">
                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M15.75 19.5L8.25 12l7.5-7.5" />
                </svg>
        </button>
        <div className="mx-auto w-[80%] overflow-x-clip py-[4%] relative">{carouselFragment}</div>
        <button onClick={slideToNextItem} className="absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 translate-x-full right-[10%]">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6 ml-10">
                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M8.25 4.5l7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5" />
                </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel2;
```

Comment: Please describe what you EXPECT to happen with the above code, what ACTUALLY happens, and any errors/exceptions that you are getting.